# Unable to write to Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Unable to get the save button (which is the tick button) to save the entry to Firebase Firestore. It always returns a failed command when pressed. It showed me a "Failed while adding detail" message when I tried to press the save button.

Here is the code for reading.

```
btn_saveentry.setOnClickListener( (v)-> saveEntry());
    }
void saveEntry(){
        String material=materialEditText.getText().toString();
        String item=itemEditText.getText().toString();
        String date=dateEditText.getText().toString();
        String note=noteEditText.getText().toString();
        Detail detail = new Detail();
        detail.setMaterial(material);
        detail.setItem(item);
        detail.setDate(date);
        detail.setNote(note);
        saveEntryToFirebase(detail);
    }
void saveEntryToFirebase(Detail detail){
        DocumentReference documentReference;
        documentReference = Utility.getCollectionReferenceForDetails().document();

        documentReference.set(detail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //detail is added
                    Utility.showToast(TrackerDetailActivity.this,"Detail added successfully");
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Utility.showToast(TrackerDetailActivity.this,"Failed while added detail");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: What exception are you actually getting? You can check `task.getException()` to find out why it failed. If you're able to read documents successfully, then my first guess would be incorrect security rules

Comment: @Michael not here if I'm doing this correctly. But this is the error message that I gotten from the Logcat whenever I click on that save button.

2024-03-03 10:12:37.923  8897-9106  Firestore               com.example.myfyp                    W  (24.10.3) [Firestore]: Write failed at trackers/PoVX77N446evkkQ30CuX5fWukDq1/mytrackers/KuMiru1YiId0dxURvjY0: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Because the Firestore rules deny your write operation. So your rules are set to deny all writes at the following location:

> trackers/PoVX77N446evkkQ30CuX5fWukDq1/mytrackers/KuMiru1YiId0dxURvjY0

If you're in the process of building the app, then you can set the default rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to read and write data until the 3rd of April, 2024. Please also remember, if you go with your app into production, don't forget to secure your database using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

If you're interested, you can also check the following resources:

- [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)

Comment: Hey Jadon. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. So can I help you w ith other information?